# Can't initialize variable in AsyncTask (inner class). What do I do?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have a bunch of calls to my database (ParseContent.queryGMG(...)) in my `AsyncTask` and I need them to all be in there or else the app loads really slow. The only one that causes the app to crash is because it's needed in other methods so I already have the variable `appAbbrev` instantiated first and then I try to have it instantiated in the `AsyncTask` inner class. Obviously this doesn't work and my app crashes. What can I do?

Works but too slow because it's in the `onCreate()` method:

```
public class ... {
    SparseArray<String> itemAction = null;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        try {
                itemAction = ParseContent.queryGMG("action");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Doesn't work because I moved it to the `AsyncTask` inner class:

```
public class ... {
    SparseArray<String> itemAction = null;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
    }
    private class Load extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            itemAction = ParseContent.queryGMG("action");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the LogCat (not sure what is relevant and how to style this):

```
01-17 17:43:31.342: E/WindowManager(32404): at            android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
01-17 17:43:31.342: E/WindowManager(32404):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3576)
01-17 17:43:31.342: E/WindowManager(32404):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:143)
01-17 17:43:31.342: E/WindowManager(32404):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
01-17 17:43:31.342: E/WindowManager(32404):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-17 17:43:31.342: E/WindowManager(32404):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-17 17:43:31.342: E/WindowManager(32404):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
01-17 17:43:31.342: E/WindowManager(32404):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-17 17:43:31.342: E/WindowManager(32404):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-17 17:43:31.342: E/WindowManager(32404):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
01-17 17:43:31.342: E/WindowManager(32404):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
01-17 17:43:31.342: E/WindowManager(32404):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-17 17:43:31.362: E/WindowManager(729): updateResizingWindows:: winAnimator.mSurfaceResized = true
01-17 17:43:31.362: E/WindowManager(729): updateResizingWindows:: winAnimator.mSurfaceResized = true
01-17 17:43:31.362: E/WindowManager(729): updateResizingWindows:: winAnimator.mSurfaceResized = true
01-17 17:43:31.512: E/Sensors(729): accelHandler -0.235909 6.980284 6.538404
01-17 17:43:31.532: E/KeyguardViewMediator(729): 3. Lockscreen unlock
01-17 17:43:31.532: E/KeyguardViewMediator(729): Phone is boot completed. so can broadcast
01-17 17:43:31.532: E/KeyguardViewMediator(729): Phone is boot completed. so can broadcast
01-17 17:43:31.532: E/MotionRecognitionService(729):   mReceiver.onReceive : ACTION_USER_PRESENT  :: UNLOCK SCREEN
01-17 17:43:31.552: E/MP-Decision(1919): mpdecision_server(): New Decision parameters Nw=1.990000, Tw=140, Ns=1.100000, Ts=190, DI=50, poll=9, util_h=70, util_l=60
01-17 17:43:31.693: E/WindowManager(729): updateResizingWindows:: winAnimator.mSurfaceResized = true
01-17 17:43:31.703: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(207): unknown stream type
01-17 17:43:31.703: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(207): unknown stream type
01-17 17:43:31.703: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(207): unknown stream type
01-17 17:43:31.703: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(207): unknown stream type
01-17 17:43:31.703: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(207): unknown stream type
01-17 17:43:31.703: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(207): unknown stream type
01-17 17:43:31.773: E/WindowManager(729): updateResizingWindows:: winAnimator.mSurfaceResized = true
01-17 17:43:31.793: E/MP-Decision(1919): mpdecision_server(): New Decision parameters Nw=2.400000, Tw=150, Ns=1.400000, Ts=100, DI=50, poll=9, util_h=100, util_l=0
01-17 17:43:31.873: E/WindowManager(729): updateResizingWindows:: winAnimator.mSurfaceResized = true
01-17 17:43:31.873: E/WindowManager(729): updateResizingWindows:: winAnimator.mSurfaceResized = true
01-17 17:43:31.873: E/WindowManager(729): updateResizingWindows:: winAnimator.mSurfaceResized = true
01-17 17:43:31.883: E/SMD(200): DCD ON
01-17 17:43:31.973: E/MTPRx(1228): In MtpReceiverandroid.intent.action.USER_PRESENT
01-17 17:43:31.973: E/MTPRx(1228): check value of boot_completed is1
01-17 17:43:31.973: E/MTPRx(1228): check booting is completed_sys.boot_completed
01-17 17:43:31.973: E/MTPRx(1228): Sd-Card path/storage/extSdCard
01-17 17:43:31.973: E/MTPRx(1228): Status for mount/Unmount :removed
01-17 17:43:31.973: E/MTPRx(1228): SDcard is not available
01-17 17:43:31.973: E/MTPRx(1228): The value of first_boot is  1
01-17 17:43:31.973: E/MTPRx(1228): [ 662] The value of first_boot is  1NORMAL SEQUENCE 
01-17 17:43:32.453: E/PowerManagerService(729): WakeLock : binderDied()
01-17 17:43:32.463: E/InputDispatcher(729): channel ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
01-17 17:43:32.473: E/MP-Decision(1919): mpdecision_server(): New Decision parameters Nw=1.990000, Tw=140, Ns=1.100000, Ts=190, DI=50, poll=9, util_h=70, util_l=60
01-17 17:43:32.944: E/ClockAlarmWidget(3842): [AlarmWidgetIdManager] getListItem() : itemIndex=0, widgetID:1
01-17 17:43:32.944: E/ClockAlarmWidget(3842): [AlarmWidgetIdManager] getListItem() : ItemIndex exceed ListItemCount. itemIndex=1
01-17 17:43:32.944: E/ClockAlarmWidget(3842): [AlarmWidgetIdManager] getListItem() : itemIndex=1, widgetID:1
01-17 17:43:34.125: E/AlarmWidget(3767): [AlarmWidgetService] getViewAt position = 0 mPosition = 3
01-17 17:43:34.125: E/AlarmWidget(3767): [AlarmWidgetIdManager] getListItem() : itemIndex=1, widgetID:12
01-17 17:43:34.145: E/AlarmWidget(3767): [AlarmWidgetIdManager] getListItem() : itemIndex=1, widgetID:12
01-17 17:43:34.155: E/AlarmWidget(3767): [AlarmWidgetService] getViewAt position = 1 mPosition = 0
01-17 17:43:34.155: E/AlarmWidget(3767): [AlarmWidgetIdManager] getListItem() : ItemIndex exceed ListItemCount. itemIndex=2
01-17 17:43:34.155: E/AlarmWidget(3767): [AlarmWidgetIdManager] getListItem() : itemIndex=2, widgetID:12
01-17 17:43:34.155: E/AlarmWidget(3767): [AlarmWidgetService] getViewAt position = 2 mPosition = 1
01-17 17:43:34.155: E/AlarmWidget(3767): [AlarmWidgetIdManager] getListItem() : ItemIndex exceed ListItemCount. itemIndex=3
01-17 17:43:34.155: E/AlarmWidget(3767): [AlarmWidgetIdManager] getListItem() : itemIndex=3, widgetID:12
01-17 17:43:34.155: E/AlarmWidget(3767): [AlarmWidgetService] getViewAt position = 3 mPosition = 2
01-17 17:43:34.165: E/AlarmWidget(3767): [AlarmWidgetIdManager] getListItem() : ItemIndex exceed ListItemCount. itemIndex=4
01-17 17:43:34.165: E/AlarmWidget(3767): [AlarmWidgetIdManager] getListItem() : itemIndex=4, widgetID:12
01-17 17:43:34.265: E/ALSAModule(207): s_standby handle h 0x41df9ed8
01-17 17:43:34.486: E/ALSAModule(207): Number of modifiers 0
01-17 17:43:34.486: E/ALSAModule(207): usecase_type is 0
01-17 17:43:34.756: E/MP-Decision(1919): DOWN Ld:24 Ns:1.100000 Ts:190 rq:0.100000 seq:196.000000
01-17 17:43:34.886: E/SMD(200): DCD ON
01-17 17:43:35.647: E/MP-Decision(1919): CPU[1] has been hotplugged outside MP-Decision.
01-17 17:43:35.647: E/MP-Decision(1919): MP-Decision will be stalled until enabled.
01-17 17:43:36.648: E/MP-Decision(1919): Enabling MP decision for CPU[1]
01-17 17:43:37.889: E/SMD(200): DCD ON
01-17 17:43:38.780: E/MP-Decision(1919): CPU[1] has been hotplugged outside MP-Decision.
01-17 17:43:38.780: E/MP-Decision(1919): MP-Decision will be stalled until enabled.
01-17 17:43:39.771: E/MP-Decision(1919): Enabling MP decision for CPU[1]
01-17 17:43:39.771: E/MP-Decision(1919): DOWN Ld:6 Ns:1.100000 Ts:190 rq:0.000000 seq:999.000000
01-17 17:43:40.882: E/SMD(200): DCD ON
01-17 17:43:41.002: E/MP-Decision(1919): CPU[1] has been hotplugged outside MP-Decision.
01-17 17:43:41.002: E/MP-Decision(1919): MP-Decision will be stalled until enabled.
01-17 17:43:41.513: E/Sensors(729): accelHandler -0.223934 6.577921 6.988667
01-17 17:43:42.014: E/MP-Decision(1919): Enabling MP decision for CPU[1]
01-17 17:43:43.385: E/MP-Decision(1919): CPU[1] has been hotplugged outside MP-Decision.
01-17 17:43:43.385: E/MP-Decision(1919): MP-Decision will be stalled until enabled.
01-17 17:43:43.485: E/Mms/MessageUtils(31975): updateCountryIso : update country iso info 
01-17 17:43:43.535: E/Mms/MessageUtils(31975): updateCountryIso : update country iso info 
01-17 17:43:43.555: E/IPPhoneSettings(31975): getString(CELL_ONLY) = 0
01-17 17:43:43.795: E/TwAdapterView(31975): TwAdapterView AdapterDataSetObserver onChanged ItemCount before onRestoreInstanceState12
01-17 17:43:43.795: E/TwAdapterView(31975): TwAdapterView AdapterDataSetObserver onChanged ItemCount after onRestoreInstanceState12
01-17 17:43:43.886: E/SMD(200): DCD ON
01-17 17:43:43.976: E/hwcomposer(204): void qhwc::QueuedBufferStore::unlockBuffer(private_handle_t*) Invalid Handle
01-17 17:43:44.206: E/TwAdapterView(31975): TwAdapterView AdapterDataSetObserver onChanged ItemCount before onRestoreInstanceState64
01-17 17:43:44.206: E/TwAdapterView(31975): TwAdapterView AdapterDataSetObserver onChanged ItemCount after onRestoreInstanceState64
01-17 17:43:44.276: E/overlay(204): Failed to call ioctl MSMFB_OVERLAY_SET err=Operation not permitted
01-17 17:43:44.276: E/overlay(204): MdpCtrl failed to setOverlay, restoring last known good ov info
```

Comment: What is `itemAction`? Is it a field of the outer class? In that case you can go `OuterClass.this.itemAction = ParseContent.queryGMG("action")`

Comment: what's in your logs ?

Comment: It *has* to be created as a member variable if you want to use it in your task class and other parts of the `Activity`. What makes you say its slow that way? `itemAction` can be initialized in your task but declared as a member variable.

Comment: @EvgenyTanhilevich sorry, I changed the code. itemAction is a local variable

Comment: @codeMagic it's because the calls to ParseContent.queryGMG(...) is slow (it's a call to the Parse.com database) and I have 3 of them. Is there no way around this? because itemAction has to be a local variable

Comment: You can make it a field.

Comment: The way you have updated your code, `OuterClass.this.itemAction = ParseContent.queryGMG("action")` will work

Comment: The second way is what you want. It shouldn't slow down your code and it makes it available to the entire `Activity`

Comment: The second way is what should make the code fast, but it always makes my app crash. I included the log cat when I do the second while WITH `OuterClass.this.itemAction`

Comment: You haven't included the **whole** logcat

Comment: @codeMagic what part should I filter so I can include the whole logcat?

Comment: Filter by error and you should get everything

Comment: @codeMagic I just did

Comment: You are right, the trace is irrelevant. You have to create a logcat filter for your app, capture the errors occurring when the said crash occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    public class MyClass {

    private SparseArray<String> itemAction;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
    }
    private class Load extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            MyClass.this.itemAction = ParseContent.queryGMG("action");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the crash log?

Comment: I just included in my original post

Comment: @ErmiasAsghedom post the full trace please